# A Question on Borel Measurable Functions

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, borel-sets

Define $A, B:[a,b] \to \mathbb R$ by
$$
A(x) = \lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \sup_{y\in [a,b]\\|x-y|<\epsilon} f(y), \quad B(x) = \lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \inf_{y\in [a,b]\\|x-y|<\epsilon} f(y),
$$
where $f:[a,b]\to\mathbb R$ is bounded function on $[a,b]$.
I want to show that

(i) $A, B$ are borel measurable functions.

(ii) If $f$ is continuous at $x_0$, then $A(x_0) = f(x_0) = B(x_0)$.

(iii) If $A(x_0) = B(x_0)$ then $f$ is continuous at $x_0$.

Actually I have no idea for (i) because I could not express $A,B$ as some limit of measurable functions. For (ii) I obtained that for any $x \in [a,b]$, $B(x) \le f(x) \le A(x)$. Please help me.

Comment: Observe that $A(x) = \inf_{\epsilon >0}\sup_{y\in [a,b]\\|x-y|<\epsilon}f(y)$ and $B(x) = \sup_{\epsilon>0} \inf_{y\in [a,b]\\|x-y|<\epsilon} f(y).
$

Comment: Is $f$ measurable?

Comment: @copper.hat I don't know. but somebody may prove that if $f$ is bounded on [a,b] then it is measurable

Comment: @K.Marlea: No, the indicator function of a non measurable set is not measurable...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll do (i) for $A$ and leave to you the specular argument for $B$.

The proof I propose can be replicated in any metric space, therefore I'll mix the general notation with the one of the real line.

Call $\mathcal B(x,r)$ the open ball centered in $x$ with radius $r$. As already pointed out, if we define, for $\varepsilon>0$ and $x\in[a,b]$, $$g_\varepsilon(x)=\sup\{f(y)\,:\,y\in \mathcal B(x,\varepsilon)\cap[a,b]\}$$ (these real numbers are well defined because $f$ is bounded) then the family of functions $(g_\varepsilon\,:\,\varepsilon>0)$ is an increasing family, id est, $$\varepsilon<\delta\implies\forall x,\ g_\varepsilon(x)\le g_\delta(x)$$ because of the fact that $\mathcal B(x,\delta)\cap[a,b]\supseteq\mathcal B(x,\varepsilon)\cap[a,b]$.

So, in order to prove that the decreasing limit $A(\bullet)=\lim_{\varepsilon\to 0^+} g_\varepsilon(\bullet)$ is a Borel function, you only need to prove that each $g_\varepsilon$ is Borel. But each of these functions is actually lower semi-continuous on the interval $[a,b]$, id est, for all $\alpha$ the set $g^{-1}_\varepsilon(\alpha,\infty):=\{x\in [a,b]\,:\, g_\varepsilon(x)>\alpha\}$ is an open subset of $[a,b]$.

In fact let $x\in g_\varepsilon^{-1}(\alpha,\infty)$. $$\sup\{f(y)\,:\,y\in \mathcal B(x,\varepsilon)\cap[a,b]\}>\alpha\iff \exists y'\in\mathcal B(x,\varepsilon)\cap[a,b],\ f(y')>\alpha$$

Since $\lvert x-y'\rvert<\varepsilon$, I claim that $\mathcal B(x,\varepsilon-\lvert x-y'\rvert)\cap[a,b]\subseteq g_\varepsilon^{-1}(\alpha,\infty)$. In fact, let $z\in\mathcal B(x,\varepsilon-\lvert x-y'\rvert)\cap[a,b]$. Then, $y'\in\mathcal B(z,\varepsilon)$, since $$\lvert z-y'\rvert\le\lvert z-x\rvert+\lvert x-y'\rvert<\varepsilon-\lvert x-y'\rvert+\lvert x-y'\rvert$$ and by definition $f(y')>\alpha$. So, indeed $g_\varepsilon(z)>\alpha$, which proves that $g^{-1}_\varepsilon(\alpha,\infty)$ is a neighbourhood in $[a,b]$ of all its points.

For $B$, there is $\inf$ instead of $\sup$, the family $(\widehat g_\varepsilon\,:\, \varepsilon>0)$ is *decreasing* (hence the limit as $\varepsilon\to 0^+$ is increasing) and there is to prove that the new $\widehat g_\varepsilon$ are *upper* semi-continuous, id est that $\widehat g_\varepsilon^{-1}(-\infty,\alpha)$ is open.

(ii) is rather obvious, and I have not much to add to the other answer.

Now, to (iii). As you've already proven, $B(x)\le f(x)\le A(x)$ always holds. Suppose $A(x_0)=f(x_0)=B(x_0)$ and assume as a contradiction that $f$ is not continuous at $x_0$. Since $[a,b]$ is a metric space, there must be a sequence $y_n\to x_0$ and a fixed $\delta>0$ such that for all $n\in\Bbb N$, $f(y_n)\in (-\infty,f(x_0)-\varepsilon)\cup(f(x_0)+\varepsilon,+\infty)$. Up to extracting a subsequence, we can assume that $f(y_n)$ lies in either of the two components. If, say, $f(y_n)\in(f(x_0)+\varepsilon,+\infty)$ for all $n$, this means that $\sup\{f(y)\,:\, \lvert x_0-y\rvert<\varepsilon\wedge y\in[a,b]\}\ge f(x_0)+\varepsilon$ for all $\varepsilon>0$, since we have the points $y_n\to x_0$. Hence, $A(x_0)\ge f(x_0)+\varepsilon$, which is absurd. Again, a specular argument works with $B$ in case $f(y_n)\in(-\infty,f(x_0)-\varepsilon)$.

Comment: For the last part, isn't it easier to take a sequence $x_n\to x_0$ and show directly that $f(x_n)\to f(x_0)$ just by using the definitions and the given inequalities?

Comment: @ChilangoIncomprendido It seems possible. I kind of wrote part (iii) as I was thinking it.

Comment: Minor correction, $A$ is usc., and $B$ is lsc. For example, if $f=1_{(0,\infty)}$ then $A = 1_{[0,\infty)}$.

Comment: @copper.hat $A$ is $\inf$ of lsc functions, therefore it might not be semi-continuous at all (it's the $\sup$ of lsc which is lsc). My argument is that $g_\varepsilon$ are lsc (and they are).

Comment: Try my little example in my last comment.

Comment: @copper.hat $$g_\varepsilon(x)=\sup\{1_{(0,\infty)}(y)\,:\,\lvert x-y\rvert<\varepsilon\}=\begin{cases}1&\text{if }x>-\varepsilon\\ 0&\text{if }x\le-\varepsilon\end{cases}=1_{(-\varepsilon,\infty)}(x)$$ which is lsc because it's the indicator of an open set. Of course, their $\inf$ is $1_{[0,\infty)}$.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/467564/27978

Comment: @copper.hat Cool, but it is stronger than what I've proved in my answer: I claim nothing on $A$ itself other than the fact that it is $\inf$ of lsc functions, hence Borel. The fact that such limit turns out to be the usc envelope is another thing (which sheds more light on the problem, actually). Can we at least agree that $\sup\{1_{(0,\infty)}(y)\,:\, \lvert y-\varepsilon\rvert<\varepsilon\}=0$? Of course, if there were a $\le$ instead of $<$, then the limit $A$ would not change and $\tilde g_\varepsilon $ would turn out to be $1_{[-\varepsilon,\infty)}$. But that's not the case here.

Comment: @copper.hat For this reason I think that yours is rather a precisation than a correction.

Comment: Sorry, my wording above was poor, it wasn't a correction, more of an observation. When I glanced at your answer originally I thought you were showing $A$ is usc. & $B$ is lsc. The continuity equivalence follows directly from the $A,B$ being usc, lsc, resp.

Comment: My original slowness stemmed from my thinking of the problem as showing that $\psi(x) = \sup_{t \in T} f(x,t)$ is measurable, and for this some form of measurability of $f$ is needed.

Answer (score 1):

$(i.)$ I can offer a proof if we assume that the functions $f_n$ defined by $f_n(x)=\sup_{y\in [a,b]\\|x-y|<1/n}f(y)$ are measurable because in this case, since $A(x)=\lim_{n\to \infty}f_n(x), A$ is also measurable. Similarly, $B$ is measurable.

$(ii).$ Let $\epsilon >0.$ Then, there is a $\delta>0$ such that $|x_0-y|<\delta\Rightarrow |f(x_0)-f(y)|<\epsilon.$ Therefore, as soon as $n\ge N=1/\delta$ we have $|f_n(x)-f(x_0)|\le \epsilon, $ which shows that $A(x_0)=\lim_{n\to \infty}f_n(x)=f(x_0).$  It is no harder to show that $B(x_0)=f(x_0).$

$(iii).$  Define $g_n$ by $g_n(x)=\inf_{y\in [a,b]\\|x-y|<1/n}f(y), $ so that $B(x)=\lim_{n\to \infty}g_n(x).$ Then, $g_n(x_0)<f(x_0)<f_n(x_0)$ and the result follows from the definition of $f_n$ and $g_n$ and letting $n\to \infty.$

Comment: Why are the functions $f_n$ measurable?

Comment: I have not been able to prove this--yet. I will assume $f$ is measurable since I am guessing that the OP meant to say so and did not.

Comment: I made a quick attempt using Lusin, but the $\sup$ is throwing me presently.

Comment: I was asleep at the wheel, f doesn't need to be measurable, will add answer when I get in front of a computer.

Comment: G. Sassatelli beat me to it.

Comment: @copper.hat really thanks for your comments. I'm waiting for your answer : )

Comment: @K.Marlea: The other answers provide all the information needed.

Answer (score 0):

The function $A$ is upper semi-continuous, which means that $L_t:=\{z:A(z)<t\}$ is open for each real $t$. One of the familiar criteria for measurability now implies that $A$ is Borel measurable.

As for the semi-continuity assertion, define $A_n(x):=\sup_{\{y:|y-x|<1/n\}}f(y)$, so that $A_n(x)$ decreases to $A(x)$ as $n\to\infty$. Fix $t\in\Bbb R$ and  $x\in L_t$. Choose (and fix) $n$ so large that $A_n(x)<t$.  If $|y-x|<1/(3n)$ then $(y-1/(3n),y+1/(3n))\subset(x-1/n,x+1/n)$ and so $A_{3n}(y)\le A_n(x)<t$. Consequently $A(y)\le A_{3n}(y)<t$. Thus, the open interval $(x-1/(3n),x+1/(3n))$ is contained in $L_t$. This shows that $L_t$ is a neighborhood of each of its points, hence $L_t$ is open.